# Inserting an element into an array in J

Tags: arrays, j

What is the best practice for inserting an element into an array at an arbitrary position in J?

I guess this is sort of a double question: my main issue is figuring out how to provide three arguments to the verb I want to create. The gist of the code that I want to write is

```
insert =. dyad : '(n {. y) , x , (n }. y)'
```

for a position `n`. The best solution to this that I can think of is taking a two-length array of boxes as the right argument and the position as the left, but that seems a bit clunky

```
insert =. dyad : 0
       NB. the array to be inserted is the first argument
       i =. > {. y
       NB. the original array is the second argument
       a =. > {: y
       (x {. a) , i , (x }. a)
)
```

EDIT: Furthermore, would it be possible to take an array of indices to insert the item at and an array of items to be inserted at those indices -- i.e. inserting multiple items at a time? It seems to me like this is something J would be good at, but I'm not sure how it would be done.

Comment: I think that you are looking for the conjunction Amend `}` http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d530n.htm

Comment: @bob perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems to me that amend replaces the item at the desired indices instead of inserting it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misread your request. Of course, you are right that amend replaces instead of inserting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boxing the arguments is an often used technique. You can use multiple assignment for cleaner code:

```
f =: 3 : 0
'arg1 arg2' =: y
)
f (i.5);(i.9)    NB. arg1 is i.5, arg2 is i.9
```

To insert array `a` at position `n` in `L`, you can more compactly write:

```
n ({., a, }.) L
```

Another way to insert an element into an array is to *fill* with `#!.`. Some examples:

```
1 1 1j2 1 (#!.999) 1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 999 999 4

1j1 1 1j1 1 (#!.999) 1 2 3 4
  1 999 2 3 999 4

1 1 0j1 1 (#!.999) 1 2 3 4
  1 2 999 4
```

Depending on your needs, there are many other tricks you can use, like shifting by n `n |.` and then undoing the shift with dual `&.`:

```
 a,&. (n |. ]) L
```

#### (reply to the comment that got too long)

Both from readability and performance standpoint the two methods are about the same. I would slightly favor the first as more readable but would probably use the second.

You can use `timespacex` verb to check the performance: eg.

```
NB. define the different methods
f1 =: 4 :'x ({., a, }.) y
f2 =: 4 :' a,&. (x |. ]) y'

NB. set some parameters
a =: 1000 $ 9
L =: 1e6 $ 5
n =: 333456

NB. check if the too methods give identical results
(n f1 L) -: (n f2 L)
1

NB. iterate 100 times to get performance averages
100 timespacex'n f1 L'
0.00775349 2.09733e7

100 timespacex'n f2 L'
0.00796431 1.67886e7
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I especially like the idea of shifting, appending, then undoing it -- that's so nifty! Are any of these more idiomatic or "preferred" (be it for runtime or readability)?

Comment: The comment got too long so I updated the answer. If performance is of an issue I would try to avoid the inserts altogether.